# SQL command not ended properly

Tags: oracle

I try to make a code in java that accesses some tables from sql but when I try to run the code I get an error saying:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly
>   ended

Here is the code that it's been giving me troubles:

```
history.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < table.getColumnCount(); j++)
                table.setValueAt("", i, j);

        int i=0;
        try
        {
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT toyname, toyid, price "
                    +" FROM toys t, userbuy u " 
                                                +" WHERE u.toyid=t.toyid "
                    +" AND u.userid= "+user1.getUserid()+" )");
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try {
                if(rs.next())
                {
                    table.setValueAt(rs.getString(1), i, 0);
                    table.setValueAt(rs.getString(2), i, 1);
                    table.setValueAt(rs.getString(3), i, 2);
                    i++;
                    while(rs.next())
                    {
                        table.setValueAt(rs.getString(1), i, 0);
                        table.setValueAt(rs.getString(2), i, 1);
                        table.setValueAt(rs.getString(3), i, 2);
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Those are my two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
  userid    NUMBER(2) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT users_pk PRIMARY KEY,
  username        VARCHAR(17) NOT NULL,
  password    VARCHAR(20),
  email   VARCHAR(20),
  adress    VARCHAR(20),
  CNP     VARCHAR(14)
);
CREATE TABLE userbuy
(
  userid    NUMBER(2),
  buyid    NUMBER(2) ,
  toyid NUMBER(2),
  CONSTRAINT userid_fk FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES users(userid),
  CONSTRAINT buyid_fk FOREIGN KEY (buyid) REFERENCES buy(buyid)
);
```

Does anyone know what is wrong here?

Comment: The `" )"` at the end of your SQL String should be removed.

Comment: You should also look at using `PreparedStatement`, as it provides (among other things) cleaner syntax than concatenating the parameter values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820183/ora-00933-sql-command-not-properly-ended)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your sql query is wrong.correct sql

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT toyname, toyid, price "
                            +" FROM toys t, userbuy u "                                                     +" WHERE u.toyid=t.toyid "
                            +" AND u.userid= "+user1.getUserid());
```

It is advisable to use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to get rid of [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Example of [PreparedStatement](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/preparestatement-object-example.htm)

Comment: I have a request for you if you are kind to help me. I'm working on a code for 2 weeks and I don't seem to get anywhere. It's my first time working with java  and sql in the same time and I don't have a clue about what I'm doing most of the time. I my opinion I think that the code is almost done but i have little errors and I don't know how to handle them. Is there any chance that you could help me?

Comment: @katy you've been told four times what the issue is. If you apply the solutions, find they are correct then come back here and mark the answer as correct, rather than just asking for more help, this will be more constructive for everyone.

Comment: @katy Sure,I will try what ever I can.Send me mail.Check my profile

Answer (score 1):

correct sql query :

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT t.toyname, t.toyid, t.price "
                  +" FROM toys t, userbuy u "+" WHERE u.toyid=t.toyid "
                   +" AND u.userid= "+user1.getUserid());
```

Answer (score 1):

remove that `" )"`, may be you forgot it :)